# Which Bioware games provide multiplayer Loyalty Packs?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I've been informed by a friend that Bioware is giving "loyalty packs" in multiplayer for players that have supported/purchased other Bioware games. What games are included for these loyalty packs? I'd love a throwback Knights of the Old Republic pack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far, the list of games that I've found that award loyalty packs include:

1. Dragon Age: Inquisition
2. Mass Effect 3

Sources include an [IGN Source](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-andromeda/Store), [Reddit Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/masseffect/comments/5zr3ir/no_spoilers_multiplayer_loyalty_packs/), and [Bioware Forum Source](http://bsn.boards.net/thread/5878/loyalty-packs-ea-access).  I also found an [EA Source](https://help.ea.com/en-us/help/mass-effect/mass-effect-andromeda/mass-effect-andromeda-pre-order-edition-rewards/) which only states these two games.  You will need to have these games linked to your account.

Comment: So much for Bioware loyalty for the long time fans!